# How to assign random number in each row of SELECT query?

Tags: sql, sqlite

I am fetching data using following query :

```
  select * from tbl_words where userID = '3'
```

This `select query` will give data as it was entered into the database.

Here I want to assign another column for random numbers. So each row will have a random number in random number column.

How do I achieve this?

Comment: random no or unique no ?

Comment: do you want to insert a random number in the row while inserting?

Comment: Should this random number be recorded into the db or just created every time you run a query?

Comment: Just created everytime. thanks for answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

RAND() (in MySQL) generates a random number between 0 and 1. Multiply by 10 to get between 1 and 10, multiple by 100 for between 1 and 100... and so on.

Thanks to Null in the comments below, RANDOM() in SQLite generates a random number between negative-silliness and positive-silliness, so there's no need to multiply by anything for SQLite.

On insert:

```
INSERT INTO table_name (column1, column2, random_number) VALUES ("something", "else", RAND() * 100000)
INSERT INTO table_name (column1, column2, random_number) VALUES ("something", "else", RANDOM())
```

On select

```
SELECT column1, column2, RAND() * 100000 AS random_number FROM table_name
SELECT column1, column2, RANDOM() AS random_number FROM table_name
```

Comment: `RANDOM()` in SQLite generates a random int between -9223372036854775808 and +9223372036854775807.

Comment: O_o Now that, I did not know. I always thought it was just a gotcha with the function name.

Comment: You can get a value in the `0 to n` range by using modulo n + 1; eg: `RANDOM() % 101` will give you a number between 0 and 100.

Comment: And it's not "between negative-silliness and positive-silliness," it's between -2^63 and +2^63 - 1, which are the minimum and maximum values for a 8-byte [2's complement integer](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Two's_complement). These things are rarely ever arbitrary

Answer (score 2):

This could work:

```
select *, random() from tbl_words where userID = '3'
```

Answer (score 2):

You need the `random()` function:

```
select t.*, random() from tbl_words t where userID = '3'
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use `random()` in your query such as

```
Select * from `yourtablename` where `yourcolumnname` order by random()
```

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT random()
UNION ALL
select * from tbl_words where userID = '3'
```

Try it did not have resrouce to test it.
Found Random from [here](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_corefunc.html)